# Why is the value of "C" changing in the following code?

Tags: c++, c, function, recursion

> the output I'm getting for the given code is "0" even though I
>   initialized the value of c as "1"...can somebody explain it...
>   Why is the value of "C" changing in the following code??

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int c=1; // global initialized 'c' as 1..

long long f(long long n){

    if(n==6){

        return 2;
    }

    else{   

        c=c+1;

        f(n-2);

    }

}
int main()
{
    long long n,ans,p;
    cin>>n;

    ans=f((2*n)-2);

    cout<<c; //printing out the value of 'c'
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you entering for n? And what compiler are you using?

Comment: If you won't / can't run the debugger, try adding a 'cout<<c<<" "'  at the begining of f().. to observe the behavior.

Comment: @stazima take value of n=3......

Comment: @ DOUGLAS O. MOEN.....yes sir i noticed the behavior but i could'nt understand the reason.....can explain it??

Answer (score 0):

Because value of c is being changed in below code :

```
else{       
        c=c+1;    
        f(n-2);    
    }
```

Comment: That depends on value of n being passed in function n. If you will keep on adding anything to c, ultimately it will overflow and could become 0.

Comment: Then it will loop forever because n will never be 6 , so it will keep on calling f(n-2); recursively , increasing value of c.